# Flutter - Size missing error on TextField

Tags: flutter

When using TextField inside a container that is centered by a parent row widget. No parents have a defined width. Container is supposed to take width of the content inside it.

Error -   `parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body (can use size) constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=1920.0, 0.0<=h<=924.0) size: MISSING behavior: opaque`

My stateless widget:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Pangea')),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.black45,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                // width: double.infinity,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextField(
                        // decoration: InputDecoration(
                        //   constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(
                        //     width: 300,
                        //   ),
                        // ),
                        ),
                  ],
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

If I use `InputDecoration` inside TextField it works fine. But I would like to keep its size dynamic. May be perhaps I can specify min and max width .

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need [IntrinsicHeight](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html) widget.
It makes its child to wait until its parent has a defined Height and, with that value in its hands, builds the child.

Comment: Doc says class is expensive and to avoid using it. So I was wondering is there not a scenario where something is written for smaller screen but can be used on large screen too. And in that case a hard coded input TextField size widget would look bad ?

Comment: @Aseem it would indeed. In your place, I'd use IntrinsicHeight (if you may afford to lose a bit of your performance to avoid hardcoded sizes). I don't know either what's your use case, but I'd also try to refactor the code in order to avoid this infinite height error.